# android - use default preference height in custom preference

Tags: android, height, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, preference

I have a custom preference:

```
public class ButtonPreference extends Preference {
    public ButtonPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public ButtonPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
        super.onCreateView(parent);
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        return li.inflate(R.layout.button_prederence, parent, false);
    }

}
```

**and xml** `button_prederence.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click me" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want all my preferences to be in the same height, so I need to get the default preference height and apply it to the `ButtonPreference`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I get this problem too.

After some research, I found this workaround method. Try to add this line in your `LinearLayout`.

```xml
android:minHeight="?android:listPreferredItemHeight"
```

or you can check the original xml file for `Preference` at 
`sdk\platforms\android-24\data\res\layout\preferences.xml`